# C, Dynamic allocation of an array of strings, success but EXC_BAD_ACCESS when printing

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, allocation

so i have the following program where i read the words from a file and i'm dynamically allocating a 2d array to put those words in. 90% of the times, this succeeds but when i try to print those words i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode or crashes in Dev C++ for some reason.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int choice = 1;
    int nWords, nCWords = 0, nVarNames = 0;
    int *histo = 0;
    char **cWords, **varNames = 0;
    char fl[20] = {0};

    printf("*~*~*~*Welcome to C Source Code Analyser*~*~*~*\n-----------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Please type the name of the source code you want to analyze including the extension <<.c>>: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s%*c", fl);

    system("cls");

    while (choice != 0)
    {
        welcomeMSG();
        scanf("%d%*c", &choice);
        selection(choice, fl, cWords, varNames, histo, &nWords, &nCWords, &nVarNames);
        if(choice != 0)
        {
            if(choice != 5) system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
    }

    freeMem(cWords, nCWords);
    freeMem(varNames, nVarNames);
    free(histo);
    return 0;

}

void freeMem(char *ptr[], int nWords)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < nWords; i++)
        if(ptr[i]) free(ptr[i]);
    ptr = NULL;
}

void sortArray(char *string[], const int size)
{
    int i, j;
    char *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(string[j], string[j+1]) > 0)
            {
                temp = string[j];
                string[j] = string[j+1];
                string[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


static int binsearch(char *str[], int max, char *value)
{
    int position;
    int begin = 0;
    int end = max-1;
    int cond = 0;

    while(begin <= end)
    {
        position = (begin + end) / 2;
        if((cond = strcmp(str[position], value)) == 0)
            return position;
        else if(cond < 0)
            begin = position + 1;
        else
            end = position - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

int isPresent(char *string[], int size, const char *value)
{
    if (size < 0) return -1;
    if (size == 0) return -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if((strcmp(string[i], value)) == 0) return i;

    return -1;
}

void welcomeMSG()
{
    printf("*~*~*~*Welcome to C Source Code Analyser*~*~*~*\n-----------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("1 - Count C words.\n");
    printf("2 - Count distinct variable names.\n");
    printf("3 - Print histogram.\n");
    printf("4 - Save statistics.\n");
    printf("Please type the number of fuction to be executed or type '0' to exit: ");
}

void selection(int choice, char *fln, char  *cWords[], char *varNames[], int *histo, int *nWords, int *nCWords, int *nVarNames)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            cntCWords(fln, cWords, nCWords);
            system("cls");
            printf("\nNumber of C words in file: %d\n", *nCWords);
            putchar('\n');
            printf("The C Words are:\n");
            printf("----------------\n\n");

            // i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS here.
            for(int i = 0; i < *nCWords; i++) puts(cWords[i]); 


            if((histo = calloc(*nCWords, sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            {
                system("cls");
                puts("\nERROR 5: Can't allocate memory. Exiting...");
                system("timeout 1 > NUL");
                free(histo);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cntVarNames();
            break;
        case 3:
            if(*nCWords == 0)
            {
                cntCWords(fln, cWords, nCWords);
                if((histo = calloc(*nCWords, sizeof(int))) == NULL)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    puts("\nERROR 6: Can't allocate memory. Exiting...");
                    system("timeout 1 > NUL");
                    free(histo);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            histogram(fln, cWords, histo, nCWords);

            int i,j;

            system("cls");
            printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%5s%*s%*s%*s%*s\n", "Num", 3, "|", 8, "Words", 3, "|", 23, "Histogram");
            printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");

            for(i = 0; i < *nCWords; i++)
            {
                printf("%4d%*s%*s%*s%*s ", histo[i], 4, "|", 10+(int)strlen(cWords[i])/2,cWords[i],10-(int)strlen(cWords[i])/2,"", 2, "|");
                for(j = 0; j < histo[i]; j++)
                    printf("*");
                printf("\n");
            }

            printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

            break;
        case 4:
            svStats();
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n*--------------------------------*\n");
            printf("   Invalid Choice. Try Again!!\n");
            printf("*--------------------------------*\n\n");
            break;
    }
}

void cntCWords(char *fln, char *cWords[], int *nCWords)
{
    char *varTypes[] = {
    "auto",   "else",     "long",   "switch",
    "break",   "enum", "register",  "typedef",
    "case", "extern",   "return",    "union",
    "char",  "float",    "short", "unsigned",
    "const",    "for",   "signed",     "void",
    "continue",   "goto",   "sizeof", "volatile",
    "default",     "if",   "static",    "while",
    "do",     "in",   "struct",   "double"
    };
    int cntWords = 0;
    char line[BufferSize];
    char *buf=0;
    char *temp[32];
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen(fln, "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        system("cls");
        puts("\nERROR 2: Can't open file. Exiting...");
        system("timeout 1 > NUL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sortArray(varTypes, 32);

    while(fgets(line, BufferSize, fp))
    {
        buf = strtok(line, DELIM);
        while(buf)
        {
            if((strlen(buf) > 0) && (buf[0] != '\t') && (buf[0] != '\n') && (buf[0] != '\0') && (buf[0] > 0))
            {
                if(binsearch(varTypes, 32, buf) != -1)
                {
                    //printf("1. %s\n", buf);
                    if((isPresent(cWords, cntWords, buf)) == -1)
                    {
                        if((temp = realloc(cWords, (cntWords + 1)*sizeof(*cWords))) == NULL)
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            puts("\nERROR 3: Can't reallocate memory. Exiting...");
                            system("timeout 1 > NUL");
                            freeMem(cWords, cntWords);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        else cWords = temp;
                        if((cWords[cntWords] = malloc((strlen(buf) + 1)*sizeof(char))) == NULL)
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            puts("\nERROR 3: Can't allocate memory. Exiting...");
                            system("timeout 1 > NUL");
                            freeMem(cWords, cntWords);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        //printf("2. %s\n", buf);
                        strcpy(cWords[cntWords++], buf);
                    }
                }
            }
            buf = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp)

    *nCWords = cntWords;

}

void histogram(char *fln, char *cWords[], int *histo, int *nCWords)
{
    int position, i;
    char line[BufferSize];
    char *buf=0;
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen(fln, "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        system("cls");
        puts("\nERROR 4: Can't open file. Exiting...");
        system("timeout 1 > NUL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < *nCWords; i++) histo[i] = 1;

    while(fgets(line, BufferSize, fp))
    {
        buf = strtok(line, DELIM);
        while(buf)
        {
            if((strlen(buf) > 0) && (buf[0] != '\t') && (buf[0] != '\n') && (buf[0] != '\0') && (buf[0] > 0))
                if((position = isPresent(cWords, *nCWords, buf)) != -1)
                    histo[position] += 1;
            buf = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

<----------------->
rest of the code
```

if i do this:

```
void cntCWords(char *fln, char *cWords[], int *nCWords)
{
    /*---------------------------------------------
                   previous code
    -----------------------------------------------*/

    fclose(fp)

    *nCWords = cntWords;

   for(int i = 0; i < *nCWords; i++) puts(cWords[i]);
}
```

and remove it from the case, then i don't get the error but if i choose the choice 3 which is the histogram i get the error at this line:

```
void histogram(char *fln, char *cWords[], int *histo, int *nCWords)
{
    /*---------------------------------------------
                   previous code
    -----------------------------------------------*/

    for(i = 0; i < *nCWords; i++) histo[i] = 1;

   /*---------------------------------------------
                   rest code
    -----------------------------------------------*/
}
```

Another example is when my first choice is 3 i get it here:

```
int isPresent(char *string[], int size, const char *value)
{
    if (size < 0) return -1;
    if (size == 0) return -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

        //i get the error here
        if((strcmp(string[i], value)) == 0) return i;

    return -1;
}

/*---------------------------------------------
                   some code
-----------------------------------------------*/

void histogram(char *fln, char *cWords[], int *histo, int *nCWords)
{
    /*---------------------------------------------
                   previous code
    -----------------------------------------------*/

    while(fgets(line, BufferSize, fp))
    {
        buf = strtok(line, DELIM);
        while(buf)
        {
            if((strlen(buf) > 0) && (buf[0] != '\t') && (buf[0] != '\n') && (buf[0] != '\0') && (buf[0] > 0))

                // when the program is here
                if((position = isPresent(cWords, *nCWords, buf)) != -1)
                    histo[position] += 1;
            buf = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: 1) We are not a "debug my code for free" site. 2) After short peek at the wall of code, there seems to be no 2D array in your code. 3) Read [ask]. And provide a [mcve], not a wall of code. 4) Start with a small project to get some practice. 5) Learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with your debugger? That should show you where the problem arises.

Comment: When you pass a pointer to a function, you can not change the caller's pointer itself.

Comment: the posted code does not compile, so how do you expect us to be able to compile/link/test/debug your code.  Amongst other problems the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements and the needed `prototypes` for the functions.

Comment: in the function: `freeMem()`, the statement: `if(ptr[i]) free(ptr[i]);` can be rewritten as: `free( ptr[i] );`  because the function: `free()` specifically checks for (and handles) a pointer containing NULL.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) respect the right hand boundary of the printed page (usually 80 columns)

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling `system()` always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the result of the call to: `welcomeMSG()` needs to be checked for validity, because the user could enter anything, including nothing but a 'return' key

Comment: The command cls is not portable (does not exist on linux (and similar). Suggest using the ANSII escape sequences, similar to: `Esc[2J`.   the command `pause` is not portable (does not exist on linux (and similar).  suggest something like: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF and && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Comment: in linux, the command: `timeout` requires a second parameter (an action to take while waiting).  So this line: `system("timeout 1 > NUL");` will fail and since the returned value from `system()` is not being checked, the posted code will never know about the failure.  The next line: `free(histo);` is not needed as the call to `calloc()` failed, so nothing to pass to `free()`

Comment: the variable/macro `BufferSize` is not defined within the scope of the posted code.  the variable/macro `DELIM` is not defined within the scope of the posted code

Comment: if this 'if' statement is true: `if((strlen(buf) > 0)` then this will never be true: `&& (buf[0] != '\0')`  .. do remember that `strlen()` with the first byte being `'\0' will return 0  AND the `&&` operators are evaluated from left to right.  Also, these two expressions: `&& (buf[0] != '\0')
                && (buf[0] > 0))` are saying the same thing due to 'implicit'conversion

Comment: this declaration, of an array of pointers to char: `char *temp[32];` means this line: if((temp = realloc(cWords, (cntWords + 1)*sizeof(*cWords))) == NULL)` is using the wrong variable type for the results of the function: `realloc()`

Comment: this expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined, in the C standard, as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect. so its' usage in a parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `*nCWords = cntWords;` the variable `nCWords` is a pointer to a pointer to an array, and the statement only dereferences the first pointer.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11 )